# How to wrap script in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jquery code which resets image sliders to slide 1 when the tabs are clicked. The problem is, it happens instantly, so you see a little flicker of the reset slider before the tab fades out.

I want to "hold" the reset back about half a second until it fades out.

I have been told I need to wrap the code in a "setTimeout" function, so I am hoping for some assistance on how to do this.

It is the "Work" section of this page that I'm talking about: www.oncreative.com.au

This is the code I have to reset the sliders:

```
<script>
    $('.reset').click(function() {
    $('.workslider').each(function() {
           var s = $(this).data('royalSlider');
           s.st.transitionSpeed = 0;
            s.goTo(0);
            setTimeout(function() {
                s.st.transitionSpeed = 600;
            }, 10); 
    });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't think we're going to be able to help you until you work out exactly what the problem is that you're having. At the moment you seem to be asking us to trawl through the JS on a production site to find your mistakes for you. If you can create a minimal example that reproduces your issue, then we can tell you what you're doing wrong, but *you'll* have to make the effort because it is *your* problem.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. Sorry I didn't realise what I was asking made it difficult. Next time I'll be more prepared. As I said, fairly new to this, so still learning how to present the issue in an easy to diagnose way. I'll suss out jsFiddle and will use that next time. I'll try myself to work out how to fix the issue with the provided code only working on the first click. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Don't be discouraged! There's an art to asking good questions, and it takes time, especially when you're new to a subject. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

```
setTimeout(function(){
 // your code here.
},500);
```

setTimeout takes two arguments - first is your code, second is the time (in milliseconds) to delay it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have just done this, and it doesn't seem to work. This is what I have (and you can check the link to see what I mean):

Comment: <script>
  setTimeout(function(){
  $('.reset').click(function() {
  $('.workslider').each(function() {
         var s = $(this).data('royalSlider');
         s.st.transitionSpeed = 0;
          s.goTo(0);
          setTimeout(function() {
              s.st.transitionSpeed = 600;
          }, 10); 
  });
  });
  },2000);
 </script>

Comment: wrap the code within the .click() function in the setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very basic jsFiddle that should provide a simple example of `setTimeout` in action: http://jsfiddle.net/A5dQn/

In your specific case:

```
// First you need to wrap the code you want to be
// executed when the timeout fires in a function:
function resetSliders () {
    $('.workslider').each(function() {
        var s = $(this).data('royalSlider');
        s.st.transitionSpeed = 0;
        s.goTo(0);
        setTimeout(function() {
            s.st.transitionSpeed = 600;
        }, 10); 
    });
};

// Then simply pass in a reference to your function to the setTimeout function.
$('.reset').click(function() { window.setTimeout(resetSliders, 500); } );
```

**Edit:** Obviously you want to wrap the code that's executed on the click event in the timeout, not the attaching of the click event itself. Sorry!

Comment: I think you have a typo in the last line - should be resetSliders()

Comment: No, that would execute `resetSliders` and pass the result into the `setTimeout`. I want to pass the function in to be executed later.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert definitely not. That would call the function, which is undesired here

Comment: Right! Sorry, shouldn't be on stack overflow while fighting a cold.

Comment: Probably worth clarifying though! That's a mistake I've made myself several times.

Comment: So, would that code above be correct, or does it need a change on the last line?

Comment: Ok, so that seems to work once, but then it doesn't work after that. But if I reload the page, it works the first time again. How can I make it so it works each time?

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the issue please?

Comment: Sorry I am a bit new to this and haven't created a jsFiddle before. I'm trying now but not having much luck...

Comment: Is it possible for you to assist with the page itself rather than jsFiddle?

Comment: Probably. But that's not really what this site's about. You're supposed to ask a specific question and get a specific answer. Not ask for help with general debugging / tutoring.

Comment: Richard, I'm just trying to answer this one query about setTimeout pausing before resetting the sliders. Not looking for general debugging. Thanks for your help so far, but I need it to work each time, not just the first time.

Comment: It *does* work every time: http://jsfiddle.net/A5dQn/. If it's not working in your case, it's because you've made a mistake. If you post a simple case that reproduces that situation, we'll help. Until then, we can only guess at your problem.